# Comment traduire "milk"

Tags: grammaire, sens, anglais, genre, oral

Bonjour,
Ca fait un mois que je cherche la traduction du mot **milk** en français.
Ne me dites surtout pas **lait** car tout les dictionnaires me traduisent **milk** en **lait** mais je crois que c'est faux.

Merci

Comment: Pour la 3ème fois, vous devez donner le contexte de ce que vous dites. On ne peut pas vous aider si vous ne donnez pas le contexte. "Milk" veut dire "lait" en français. Donc si ça ne vous plait pas, dites nous pourquoi, et on vous aidera à trouver une autre traduction. Mais là, on ne sait pas ce que vous voulez, on ne peut pas vous aider... (Casey à déjà fait beaucoup comparé au peu que vous avez donné...)

Comment: il y a *laiteux*, qui veut dire "milky", et non "milk"

Comment: nn c'est bon j'ai trouvé le mot c'est laituoso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il faudrait que vous donniez plus de contexte au terme "milk" car le mot n'a pas beaucoup d'usages en anglais.

A part **lait**," "milk" peut vouloir dire:

**extraire** ou **traire** (dans le cas où l'on extrait du lait d'un animal), ou

**pomper** (par exemple : Le patron a pompé l'énergie de ses employés jusqu'à la dernière goutte.

Sans contexte, par contre, c'est très difficile de savoir ce que vous cherchez.

Comment: a white liquid produced by a woman to feed her baby or by female animals to feed their young; especially : milk from cows or goats that is used as food by people

Comment: Le « lait maternel » peut être humain, si c'est le fait d'appeler ça du « lait » qui te dérange. Mais si c'est le contexte de ta phrase, édites ta question avec ce dernier.

Comment: i dont like the word lait so i search for an other

Comment: Édite ta question avec ce genre d'informations alors. Car tu ne peux pas dire "je crois que c'est faux" sans contexte ! Le fait que tu n'aimes pas ce terme ne veut pas dire qu'il est incorrect ! Tu sembles chercher un synonyme !

Comment: et si on utilise laituoso ca serait mieux

Comment: En quoi `laituoso` est mieux ? D'où vient ce mot ?

Comment: La ministra boit du laituoso . ca sonne bien pourtant